# Can I return different razor views on .NET controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The background is this. I have a controller that shows the details of an story object (which you can think of as a blog post).

I would like anyone to be able to read the details of a story without being logged in to the application. However, in my `StoryDetailsViewModel` I have an `ApplicationUser` field. I do this because if someone wants to comment on the story, I need to know who the author is and therefore, I want to force them to log-in to write a comment.

I have `[AllowAnonymous]` as an attribute on my controller action. When I try to get the identity of the user who's signed in, if the person is not signed in, the call returns null, sticks null in my `ApplicationUser` field in the viewmodel and consequently breaks the view. My controller action is below.

This whole thing is because in the view, I want this textarea if someone is logged in:

[image]

I don't know whether or not I should have some kind of boolean that if `User.Identity.GetUserId()` returns null I can act on that, or, as the controller action below has, try to create two separate viewmodels depending on if the user is anonymous or logged in.

Any thoughts on the best (most efficient) way to tackle this?

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var FoundStory = _dbContext.Stories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        if (FoundStory == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        //get the logged in userId
        string signedInUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        //if the person reading the article isn't signed in, the userId will come back null
        //need to create a viewmodel and view that doesn't have a signed in user associated with it
        if (signedInUserId == null)
        {
            var viewModel = new StoryDetailsViewModelAnonymousUser
            {
                StoryId = FoundStory.Id,
                AuthorId = FoundStory.AuthorId,
                Story = FoundStory,
                Comments = _dbContext.Comments.Where(x => x.StoryId == FoundStory.Id).ToList()
            };

            return View(viewModel);

        } else
        {
            var viewModel = new StoryDetailsViewModelSignedInUser
            {
                StoryId = FoundStory.Id,
                AuthorId = FoundStory.AuthorId,
                Story = FoundStory,
                User = _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == signedInUserId),
                Comments = _dbContext.Comments.Where(x => x.StoryId == FoundStory.Id).ToList()
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

My viewModel:

```
public class StoryDetailsViewModelSignedInUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public int StoryId { get; set; }
        public Story Story { get; set; }

        public string AuthorId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you won't need a new View in this case. You can add a `bool` property such as `IsAnonymous` to `StoryDetailsViewModelSignedInUser` to indicate if a user is logged in or not, or check if property `User` is set (`model.User != null`) and then, in the view, show or hide the Comments section/partial view using these properties

Comment: I agree. It was the simplest thing to implement rather going through the process of doing two views.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of some code duplication - that `if (signedInUserId == null){...} else {...}` can be simplified, see https://pastebin.com/1Fb83pcE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you probably don't need to use different views.

You can add a `bool` property such as `IsAnonymous` to `StoryDetailsViewModelSignedInUser` to indicate if a user is logged in or not, or check if property `User` is set (`model.User != null`). Finally, in your view, show or hide the Comments section/partial view using these properties.

ViewModel:

```
public class StoryDetailsViewModelSignedInUser
{
    public bool IsAnonymous
    {
        get
        {
            return User != null;
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    // other properties here
}
```

Using a partial view for your comments section will probably make your life easier, given that all you have to do is to add an `if` statement checking if the user is logged in or not.

I'd also refactor the controller method in order to reduce code duplication. Instead of:

```
if (signedInUserId == null)
{
    var viewModel = new StoryDetailsViewModelAnonymousUser
    {
        StoryId = FoundStory.Id,
        AuthorId = FoundStory.AuthorId,
        Story = FoundStory,
        Comments = _dbContext.Comments.Where(x => x.StoryId == FoundStory.Id).ToList()
    };

    return View(viewModel);

} else
{
    var viewModel = new StoryDetailsViewModelSignedInUser
    {
        StoryId = FoundStory.Id,
        AuthorId = FoundStory.AuthorId,
        Story = FoundStory,
        User = _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == signedInUserId),
        Comments = _dbContext.Comments.Where(x => x.StoryId == FoundStory.Id).ToList()
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

You can do:

```
var viewModel = new StoryDetailsViewModelAnonymousUser
{
    StoryId = FoundStory.Id,
    AuthorId = FoundStory.AuthorId,
    Story = FoundStory,
    Comments = _dbContext.Comments.Where(x => x.StoryId == FoundStory.Id).ToList()
};

if (signedInUserId != null)
{
    viewModel.User = _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == signedInUserId);
}

return View(viewModel);
```